# Singularity of $z^3\cos(\frac1z)$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=z^3\cos(\frac1z)$ has an isolated singularity at $z=0$ because it is holomorphic on the punctured neighborhood of $0$.

I learned that $f$ has removable singularity iff $\lim\limits_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$ so in this case since $zf(z)=z^4\cos(\frac1z)\to 0$ as $z\to 0$ by squeeze theorem, we have a removable singularity at $z=0$.

But in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity, it says in the middle of the page that if $\lim\limits_{z\to a} f(z)$ exists but $\lim\limits_{z\to a}\frac{1}{f(z)}$ does not exist, then $a$ is a zero of $f$ and a pole of $1/f$. So we have "zero" at $f(a)$, which doesn't seem right.

I'm confused. Which argument is correct?

Comment: Now that I see, maybe it's not an isolated singularity at all....

Comment: In fact $z^4\cos(1/z)$ does _not_ tend to $0$ at the origin! Most likely you were assuming that $|\cos|\le1$.

Comment: Ahh yes, you're right. I think it IS an isolated singularity, right? Because $z=0$ is the only point that is not defined.

Comment: I think I can let $z=x+iy$ and try to calculate the limit, but it becomes very cumbersome and I don't know how to determine it

Comment: The power series for $\cos(z)$ leads immediately to the Laurent series for $\cos(1/z)$.

Comment: Oh, so it has infinite terms for principal part, so has an essential singularity.

Comment: Remember that $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$, which means $\cos z$ is an *exponential function in disguise*. On real axis ($z=x\in\mathbb R$) it behaves like $\cos x$, on imaginary axis ($z=iy, y\in\mathbb R$) it behaves as $\cosh y$ and goes to $+\infty$ (exponentially!) as $y\to\pm\infty$. Thus, across certain paths, $\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ goes to infinity as $z\to 0$ - again, exponentially. The factor $z^4$ cannot "counter" that.